# Recent install of 22.04 Jammy...will not upgrade to 22.10

Tags: 22.10

Recent 22.10 disk crash has me installing on a new HDD. I installed 22.04.3 from USB thumb drive and it's install as Jammy. But when I try to install/upgrade 22.10 as required, it won't install.

Shows:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gjs libgjs0g
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Kept back error fixed.

Sudo apt upgrade doesn't install.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Downloaded 23.04 to a thumb drive and installed it erasing 22.04. Working fine and I'm back to getting everything running again-again-again. I have 50 odd passwords for pages I'm on it's a bit frustrating.

Comment: perhaps the issue here is that 22.10 already went EOL - see [wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: Perhaps but nothing I've read on the web has said that's the case AND according to what I read, you have to go 22.04 to 22.10 before going to 23.04 and so on. Okay, started downloading 23.04 and we'll see if that works.

Comment: Indeed, you have to do that, but that is only (officially) possible during the support life time of 22.10. So at this time, you are better off with a fresh install.